# Lighting setup for C4D

Tags: 3d, lighting-effects

I'm learning lighting now and was curious how this pictures was made, maybe someone have idea what kind of light scheme used here
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me they both look like classic **low-key** setups.

The **upper image** has a two light setup with a low-intensity key that's basically white behind the subjects and quite low (probably a luminous poly based on the implied area) and a lower-level blue-shifted rimlight to the high right, also behind the subjects (as most rim lights are). There *may* also be a secondary key source down near the main white key, but a bit closer to the subjects and more upwardly-pointed that is significantly red, but it's unclear - that colour-cast *may* be coming from subsurface scatter from part of the subject geometry.

The **lower image** looks like a single luminous poly light source that's quite large, off to the image left and in front of the subject but not by a lot. The subject's surface is very smooth in terms of topology, and the texture looks like a satin or matte finish of some kind, but with little or no subsurface scatter.

You ***really*** should look up "low-key lighting" in photography fora, especially those which cater to beginners and those interested in portraiture - most good render lighting is directly imitative of (or deeply influenced by) traditional photographic lighting techniques and concepts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Gerard, Thanks a lot for this great answer! You really helped me

Comment: @NicoleMlinova I’m super glad you found my answer helped you out - if you found that my answer indeed solved your issue, please “accept” it - it helps our stats as a community and gives both you and I gain reputation into the bargain!